android room Database relationships kotlin
I have three tables trainList, Schedule, Stations
@Entity("TrainList")
data class TrainTable(
    @PrimaryKey
    val number:String="",
    val name:String="",
    val sourceName:String="",
    val sourceCode:String="",
    val destinationName:String="",
    val destinationCode:String=""
)
@Entity("Schedule", primaryKeys = ["stationCode","trainNumber"])
data class Sched`your text`uleTable(
    val trainNumber:String="",
    val stationCode:String="",
    val arrivalTime:Int=0,
    val departureTime:Int=0,
)
@Entity("Stations")
data class StationTable(
    @PrimaryKey
    val stationCode:String="",
    val stationName:String="",
    val lat:Double=0.0,
    val lng:Double=0.0
)

how can i link TrainTable to ScheduleTable and schedule to stations, so that when ever i query train Schedule i should get train details from train table and schedule from schedule table and station details corresponding to that station from schedule table.
tables are as follow
Train Table



number
name
SourceName
SourceCode
destName
destCode




12232
XYZC
ABCD
ABC
EFGA
efg


13005
QWER
XYZQ
xyz
DCBA
dca



Schedule Table



trainNumber
stationCode
arrivalTime
departureTime




12232
abc
1510
1510


12232
bce
1540
1545


12232
cde
1610
1640


13005
def
1705
1710


13005
efg
1805
1810



one train could have multiple stops i.e. this table has two primary keys
Station Table



stationCode
stationName
lat
lng




abc
ABCD
15.10
1.510


bcd
BCDE
15.40
15.45


efg
CDEF
16.10
16.40


dca
DEFG
17.05
17.10


xyz
EFGH
18.05
18.10



lets say i query train schedule of 12232
I should get train details from train table i.e. number, name, sourceName, sourceCode and so on, and all the stops of that train from the schedule table and station details corresponding to that stop.
12232 XYZCD ABCD abc(abc, ABCD, 15.10, 1.510) EFGH efg( efg, CDEF, 16.10,16.40)
stops
abc(abc, ABCD, 15.10, 1.510) 1510 1510
efg( efg, CDEF, 16.10,16.40) 1510 1510
efg( efg, CDEF, 16.10,16.40) 1510 1510
efg( efg, CDEF, 16.10,16.40) 1510 1510
I tried to link them but able to get required output
With this relationships
data class TrainWithScheduleAndStations
    (
    @Embedded val train: TrainTable= TrainTable(),
    @Relation(

        parentColumn = "number",
        entityColumn = "trainNumber"
    )
    val schedules: List<ScheduleTable> = emptyList(),
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "sourceCode",
        entityColumn = "stationCode"
    )
    val fromStation: StationTable = StationTable(),
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "DestinationCode",
        entityColumn = "stationCode"
    )
    val toStation: StationTable = StationTable()
)


i get this answer
12232  XYZCD ABCD abc(abc, ABCD, 15.10, 1.510) EFGH efg( efg, CDEF, 16.10,16.40)
stops
abc 1510 1510
efg 1510 1510
efg 1510 1510
efg 1510 1510
But required is this
12232  XYZCD ABCD abc(abc, ABCD, 15.10, 1.510) EFGH efg( efg, CDEF, 16.10,16.40)
stops
abc(abc, ABCD, 15.10, 1.510) 1510 1510
efg( efg, CDEF, 16.10,16.40) 1510 1510
efg( efg, CDEF, 16.10,16.40) 1510 1510
efg( efg, CDEF, 16.10,16.40) 1510 1510
I am not able to link Station table

You need to consider the hierarchy. That is a schedule will have it's related station. So something like:-
data class ScheduleWithStation(
    @Embedded
    val schedule: ScheduleTable,
    @Relation(
        entity = StationTable::class, parentColumn = "stationCode", entityColumn = "stationCode"
    )
    val station: StationTable
)

To incoporate this so that you get A Train with it's List of schedules AND with the schedules station then you can incorporate the above to use something like:-
data class TrainSourceAndDestAndWithScheduleWithStations(
    @Embedded
    val train: TrainTable,
    @Relation(
        entity = StationTable::class, parentColumn = "sourceCode", entityColumn = "stationCode"
    )
    val fromStation: StationTable,
    @Relation(
        entity = StationTable::class, parentColumn = "destinationCode", entityColumn = "stationCode"
    )
    val toStation: StationTable,
    @Relation(
        entity = ScheduleTable::class, parentColumn = "number", entityColumn = "trainNumber"
    )
    val schedulesWithStations: List<ScheduleWithStation>
)

This would then produce, for example, :-
TrainName=XYZC Number=12232 
    
        FromStation=ABCD Code=abc Lat=15.1 Lng=1.51
        To  Station=EFGH Code=efg Lat=18.05 Lng=18.1
        There are 3 Schedules. They are:-
            Arrival=1510 Depart=1510 Train#=12232 StationName= ABCD Code=abc Lat=15.1 Lng=1.51
            Arrival=1540 Depart=1545 Train#=12232 StationName= BCDE Code=bcd Lat=15.4 Lng=15.45
            Arrival=1610 Depart=1640 Train#=12232 StationName= CDEF Code=cde Lat=16.1 Lng=16.4




TrainName=QWER Number=13005 
    
        FromStation=XYZI Code=xyz Lat=18.05 Lng=18.1
        To  Station=DCAJ Code=dca Lat=18.05 Lng=18.1
        There are 2 Schedules. They are:-
            Arrival=1705 Depart=1710 Train#=13005 StationName= DEFG Code=def Lat=17.05 Lng=17.1
            Arrival=1805 Depart=1810 Train#=13005 StationName= EFGH Code=efg Lat=18.05 Lng=18.1


note results are based upon the data from the question (but with some changes to circumvent referential integrity issues with the data in your question e.g. bcd/bce)

